# How to rename a folder in Linux?

Tags: linux, mv

I want to remove folder `aaa` and rename folder `bbb` to `aaa`. Both have subfolders in them.

Seems simple enough using:

```
rm -r aaa; mv bbb aaa
```

However, any subfolders in `bbb` disappear where I would expect them to stay in `bbb` (now `aaa`).

I can get around this using:

```
rm -r aaa; cp -r bbb aaa; rm -r bbb;
```

But this seems a long-winded way around it.

I have read about using `-r` with `mv`, but apparently this isn't possible (if it ever was).

My question is, how do I rename (move) a folder and keep its subfolders?

Comment: You should remove directories with `rmdir` (if they are empty). If they have subdirectories or files, use `rm -R` (or if you are   venturous `rm -Rf` to delete without asking). And: `mv -r` is not needed, because `mv` just renames (moves to a new name) a directory (or file) independent of its content.

Comment: Sorry I should have clarified that. I am using -r with rm to remove all subfolders. but when I used mv it does not keep the subfolders in bbb when it becomes aaa - I need these subfolders as well.

Comment: `mv bbb aaa` *is* the proper command for that. `mv` doesn't *move* anything in this case, it just renames the folder. Is it possible you made a mistake?

Comment: I've double checked my code using mv (my first code example), and it has kept the subfolders - so I don't know what I managed to do the first time around. Sorry for wasting your time and thanks for the assistance.

Comment: You can execute `history` to check what went wrong the last time.